# Removing Many Backslashes in a string

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a string that I get from a database with has many backslashes in. I need to take them all out. I have been playing with the .replace function however because there is an undefined number of backslashes I can't work out how to do it.

Any help is much appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
var str = 'str //// str';
str = str.replace(/\//g,''); // edited to match the comment of jiduvah
```

Comment: Actually `str.replace(/\\/g,'');`, because \ is a special character.

Comment: I guess there is some problem here replace(//g,''); Eclipse is highlighting an error

Comment: No luck unfortunately this doesn't work. To be clear I here is an example of a string

string////////string/////////////////

Comment: These are not backslashes. :) They are slashes and you should use `str.replace(/\//g,'');`.